# ToolStripMenuItem click event should return a class

Tags: c#, winforms

I had a `DataGrid` and a `ContextMenuStrip` in it. When I click `SelectMenuStrip` in a row I want the `ClickEvent` of the context menu to get all data in that row in a `databean` class and return that `databean` class, so that I can fill the data in another class-
All was fine I defined event as below

```
private CustomerDataBean toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerDataBean custdatabean = null;

    int rowno = tblcustomerdataview.CurrentCellAddress.Y;
    custdatabean.Customerpk = int.Parse(tblcustomerdataview.Rows[rowno].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    custdatabean.Contactno = tblcustomerdataview.Rows[rowno].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        custdatabean.Emailid = tblcustomerdataview.Rows[rowno].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    custdatabean.Other = tblcustomerdataview.Rows[rowno].Cells[8].Value.ToString();

    return custdatabean;
}
```

but in `designer.cs` I am getting an error in line:

```
this.toolStripMenuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem1_Click);
```

The error is:

> Error 1: 
>   'WindowsFormsApplication3.CustomerDataBean WindowsFormsApplication3.CustomerSearch.toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' has the wrong return type  D:\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Merchandising\customerSearch.Designer.cs 83 46 NFTRANS

Where have I done something wrong?
Let me explain the situation
I had a jobcodeform where user should input the customercode in combobox if he forget customercode he can use a buton to go to another form called customersearch where there is a datagrid table with a context menustrip which when clicked gets the whole details of the selected row in a customerdatabean and return that back to the first jobcodeform

Comment: the system events return nothing because it means you want to return the class to windows. and where do you want to return it? ---------- `MouseEventHandler` is a `delegate` and it gets just void method with tow parameters. you can't add different methods to the delegates and expected to the work fine. ---------- why do you not call a method and do your works there?

Comment: The standard events return `void` because they are multicast.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: But it think the reason is that the method returns to the `system` and not return tho the `code`.

Comment: Not to the 'system' but to the virtual OmMenuItemClick() method. You could get the result, with some effort.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense.  Click events don't return anything (except void), they really just run a procedure.

Your quick fix is to match the signature of the handler:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // do something, don't return anything
}
```

What you need to define is what are you trying to do with your `CustomerDataBean` object.  If you are just trying to add it to a list, then add it to a list:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CustomerDataBean custdatabean = new CustomerDataBean();
  // set properties    
  myBeans.Add(custdatabean);
}
```

The code you currently have doesn't even create a CustomerDataBean object. It's null, and then you are trying to update a null object.  That isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself where should your click event return the object to?
What code will process that bean?

The others have explained what is wrong with your click event.

Here's one possible method:

Have your click event call a separate method to process the bean.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerDataBean custdatabean = null;

    int rowno = tblcustomerdataview.CurrentCellAddress.Y;
    custdatabean.Customerpk = int.Parse(tblcustomerdataview.Rows[rowno].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    custdatabean.Contactno = tblcustomerdataview.Rows[rowno].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        custdatabean.Emailid = tblcustomerdataview.Rows[rowno].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    custdatabean.Other = tblcustomerdataview.Rows[rowno].Cells[8].Value.ToString();

    processBean(custdatabean);
}

private void processBean(CustomerDataBean bean)
{
    //Code to process the bean here.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

ToolStripMenuItem click event handlers need to return void.

Comment: Since you're new to Stack Overflow, I'll give you a tip. When you want to comment, post a comment.

Comment: That wasn't a comment. It was an answer. His code is trying to return an object from a click event handler, and those need to return void.

Comment: An answer would include 'why' and preferably an alternative. You are just repeating the error msg.

Comment: The error message says 'WindowsFormsApplication3.CustomerDataBean WindowsFormsApplication3.CustomerSearch.toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' has the wrong return type D:\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Merchandising\customerSearch.Designer.cs 83 46 NFTRANS. Mine is much clearer, and states specifically why this error pops up. Because click event handlers must return void.

Comment: @Almo: and you just filtered the increscent text from message.

Comment: The original text says that the function has the wrong return type. The function is defined to return a CustomerDataBean and it attempts to return a CustomerDataBean, and it says it's the wrong return type. That's not useful. I have explained why he gets this error: because click event handlers must return void.